# Website structure got out when zoom-out

Tags: html, css

I am working on that website 
https://steelmountain.io/new/

I tried to fix css but still zoom-out the website its gone worst.

Can someone please help me to fix my mistake.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify the specific problem and provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help demonstrate.

Comment: If you just zoomout you can see the layout getting out .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "getting out". Also, please "Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem... Include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." -- [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I mean its messing up , elements are not center-aligned , its overlapping each other

Comment: Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/4642212). As soon as you fix your site, this question will be of no value to future readers.

Answer (score -1):

Layout seems fine to me honestly, at least from a desktop point of view. When you alter the screen height/width there are a few overlapping elements, which can be fixed by adding spacing, padding, and margins within the corresponding css `@media`. Use percentages to ensure that pixelation does not remain constant

For instance,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .hero__form .form-control {
        padding-top: 10%
    }
}
```